# Changing to timeGridDay when clicking on show more FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'd like to change to current day timeGridDay view on FullCalendar when clicking on "+x more" on DayGridWeek view.
[image]
When I click on tue 1/8 +6 more, I would change to this view :
[image]
Does anyone knows how can I do it ? I'm using FullCalendar V6 on VueJS

```
    <full-calendar
      ref="calendar"
      :options="calendarOptions"
    />
----------------------------------------------------------------
 data: function () {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'timeGridDay, timeGridWeek, dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek next',
        },
        eventClick: (eventClickInfo) => {
          this.expandEvent(eventClickInfo);
        },
        datesSet: () => {
          this.handleCalendarUpdate();
        },
        locale: this.$store.getters.fullCalendarLocale,
        lazyFetching: true,
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, rrulePlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        weekends: true,
        events: [],
        selectable: true,
        dayMaxEvents: 3,
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        slotEventOverlap: false,
      },
```

I don't know what to do, actually

Comment: This is not currently supported in fullcalendar. If you would like it to be possible, read https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features